# VestaCP/exim mail server returns 550 smtp auth requried

Tags: email, smtp, exim

I have just installed VestaCP on a fresh CentOS VPS.

I have set up email for one domain. All mail sent to that domain bounces with the error 550 smtp auth requried

I have commented out the following;

```
deny    message       = smtp auth requried
```

from exim.conf

I have turned off anti-spam.

I still get the bounce with this message.

Specifically, if I send an email from a gmail account google responds:

```
Technical details of permanent failure: 
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain foobar.tld by mail.foobar.tld. [x.x.x.x].

The error that the other server returned was:
550 smtp auth requried
```

Any experience with this? I have seen the problem on a number of threads but have not found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved the problem. It only occurred when sending mail to the smtp server from a domain that was hosted on the same server for web but *not* for email. When I sent email from a domain that had nothing to do with any domains hosted on the same server as the exim instance, then it got through. I still can't send email from the domain that was causing the problem and I would like to, but I can work around it.

So to be clear in case anyone reads this:

domain1 web is hosted on server1

domain1 email is hosted on google's servers

domain2 is hosted on server1 for web and email

exim is running on server1

when I send email from thunderbird via google's server from email@domain1 to and email@domain2 the exim instance asks google's smtp server for authentication even though the mail is being delivered to a mailbox in its list of domains it can deliver to on the same physical server where it is running.

I suspect that it is suspicious of the from address, which it shouldn't be since the mx records indicate that it does not host mail for that domain.